# Django optimized query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `Personne` and each person may be linked to another person via a `PersonneRelation` model:

```
class Personne(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonneRelation',
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       related_name='personne_relations')

class PersonneRelation(BaseModel):
    type_relation = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(a, b) for a, b in list(PersonneEnums.TAB_RELATIONS.items())],
        default=PersonneEnums.RELATION_FRIEND)
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='relation_src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='relation_dst')
    is_reverse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So, imagine one person **`A`**. He has a contact **`B`**. My client wants me to display all the contacts of **`B`** so that **`A`** might be able to send a message to those contacts. Pretty easy. The problem is that I've made a view that displays the "person" information and it's pretty simple, like `/person/{id}`. Thus if you change the `{id}` value, you can see another person information. What I need to check is:

- if the person to display is a contact of **`A`**
- if the person to display is a contact... of a contact of **`A`**

For now I'm doing an ugly query where I check all the contacts... of all the contacts of **`A`**.

How would you do an optimized query to check if the person to display is a contact... of a contact of **`A`**?

Comment: Can you also add the queries you have written for the two cases above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns `True`, if `user` can see `other`'s information. `user` and `other` are instances of `auth.User`.

```
user.personne.relations.filter(
    Q(user=other) | Q(relations__user=other)
).exists()
```

Comment: Wow nice idea I'll check it asap